# Attach constructor function method as handler using jQuery

Tags: javascript

So, I have this:

```
function foo(){

  var that = this;

  this.elements = [
    $bar = $('.bar'),
    $foo = $('.foo')
  ];

  this.example = function(){
    alert("a");
  }

  this.elements.$bar.on('click', that.example);
}
```

and it's not working, however if I change this line:

```
  this.elements.$bar.on('click', that.example);
```

for this one:

```
  this.elements.$bar.on('click', function(){ that.example() });
```

That is, wrapping the method into an anonymous function, it does work...

**EDIT**: It also works if the method is not within the constructor function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's nothing wrong with how you attach your method in your current code. Though I notice that you've called your DOM Element like this:

```
this.elements = [
    $bar = $('.bar'),
    $foo = $('.foo')
];

this.elements.$bar
```

Instead, try to assign them as an object:

```
this.elements = {
    $bar : $('.bar'),
    $foo : $('.foo')
 };
```

Then in your code:

```
this.elements.$bar.on('click', that.example);
```

Here's a sample jsfiddle for further details: 
http://jsfiddle.net/b1bsc1rd/

Hope this helps for you

Comment: Oh, I figured it out, the event attachment has to be after the method, otherwise it's undefined and jQuery ignores it and doesn't throw any error, if you want, edit your answer so this can be useful to others that in the future may have the same question.